# Duplicating a control in wpf application-xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to show a duplicate of a control which behaves same as source.In below mentioned code I have textbox1 that I want to show again.So I created one more text and binded its text with textbox1's text.If I change the text in textbox1 ,text changes in other tetxbox also.

But my problem is validation template is not getting applied on other control.How can I do that?

```
<TabItem Width="100" Height="50" Header="Tab1">
    <AdornerDecorator>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label> First</Label>
                <TextBox x:Name="TextBox1"
                         Margin="20"  Height="50" Width="150"
                         Style="{StaticResource S_ErrorTemplate}" 
                         Text="{Binding TestValue, 
                         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                         NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                <TextBox Margin="20"  Height="50" Width="150"
                         Style="{StaticResource S_ErrorTemplate}"  
                         Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1, Path=Text,
                         ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,
                         NotifyOnValidationError=True,
                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                         Template="{Binding ElementName=TextBox1,Path=Template}"/>  
        </StackPanel>
    </AdornerDecorator>
</TabItem>
```

output is

[image]

Comment: Why not just bind it to TestValue as well?

Comment: @LeeO. I know it can be done that way,but thats the root of my problem  where it got started.Actually TestValue is a float datatype in view model so  when i use binding at both place.It works fine in case of numerics ,I see same values in both boxes and same validation error.But in case of alphabets I dont get the same validation error in other box  because value is not set to binded property.Thats why I thought it will be good idea to duplicate the control and asked this question.I really don't have flexibility to change the datatype in my actual project.

Comment: As i see you don't have a style applied Style="{StaticResource S_ErrorTemplate}" to the second textbox.

Comment: @IvanZub I applied the style also,still doesn't solve the problem.